# Force resolutions seems not to work for the dependencies of 'root' package.json

Tags: npm, npm-install

In my application's `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
     "axios": "0.21.2",
     ....
},
"resolutions": {
    "axios": "0.24.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
     ...
}
```

However, the 'axios' version that is installed is **0.21.2**. I would expect to be **0.24.0**. What am I missing? When doing that for nested dependencies, they are forced to use the version defined in resolutions rather than this defined in their package.json. Why it is not the case with the app's package.json?

Answer (score 0):

In package.json add something like this to resolve any grapahql package (replace with your package of issue) to the specified version.

```
  "resolutions": {
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "**/graphql": "^15.8.0"
  },
```